# How to Get which Radio Button is Checked in a Groupbox then insert it to a database vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, forms, radio-button

I want to insert a record in a database with two Groupbox. rdGender (has Male and female radio buttons) and rd ( has Owner and Driver radio buttons) in vb.net

[image]

Comment: What has getting a `RadioButton` got to do with saving data to a database. They are two completely separate issues. This is one of the reasons that beginners have trouble solving problems: because they treat multiple problems as one and expect to be able to find a single solution. Saving data to a database is the same no matter where the data comes from. Learn how to save data to a database and you can do it for any data. Getting the data in any particular situation is a completely separate question.

Comment: SO requires that you ask a single, specific question at a time. I answered the bit about the `RadioButton` before I realised there was a bit about a database as well. Edit your question to be about one specific thing - the `RadioButton` in this case. You can then ask a separate question about saving to a database if you need to, but the `RadioButton` will be irrelevant to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to use a bit of LINQ, e.g.

```vb
Dim checkedRadioButton = myGroupBox.Controls.
                                    OfType(Of RadioButton)().
                                    FirstOrDefault(Function(rb) rb.Checked)
```

That will give you the `RadioButton` that is checked or `Nothing` if none is checked. That means that you'll have to test for `Nothing` before using the value of the variable. If you know for a fact that one will be checked, e.g. one is checked by default or you don't enable a `Button` to save until one is, then you can use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and omit the null check.